# Multiboot Windows 7, Windows 10, Debian, FreeBSD

Tags: multi-boot, grub2

I am attempting to set up my workstation with the following OS and Grub as a boot-loader:

- Windows 7
- Windows 10
- Debian Jessie
- FreeBSD 11.0

All the above OS are installed on separate hard drives. I ran into the following issues:

1. Windows 10 is installing a boot-loader which allows me to run Windows 7 and Windows 10. Debian and FreeBSD are ignored. Grub is bypassed;
2. Windows 10 is not listed in the Grub entry menu. It is still possible to access it by selecting Windows 7, then a new boot-loader appears;
3. Grub is ignored, Windows 10 cannot be launched (A hard drive issue is detected);
4. Grub is ignored.

I am running an UEFI bios.

I tried to install everything in UEFI mode, without any success (I ended up with the fourth issue mentioned above).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your replies.

PS: Everything run as expected if I do not install Windows 10.

Comment: If you install all OS in HDDs then try to repair the grub bootloader. Or install Debian at last. See this [discussion](https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/60141)

Comment: @Biswa I am always installing debian at last. Already tried boot repair without success.

Answer (score 2):

After several other attempts, I finally managed to install all those systems.

I did not notice the override options in my bios (determines which device to boot if the current one is bypassed). Windows 7 and Windows 10 were not installed in UEFI mode, even if DVDs were launched in UEFI.

For obscure reasons, I had to create `.iso` images of my Windows DVDs and make bootable USB devices. It was impossible to install Windows in UEFI mode with DVDs.

The guide below has been written in order to help users who are getting troubles to install their OS in UEFI mode. Several terms used to describe bios settings may not be the same as yours due to material and software differences.

I used Rufus for creating bootable USB devices. Do not forget to select `GPT partition scheme for UEFI`. You can also use `diskpart`.

### First step: Installing Windows 7

1. Enter your bios;
2. Disable `Boot secure`;
3. Unload `Platform key state` (depending on your bios, it will also disable `Boot secure`);
4. Set `OS type` to `Windows UEFI`;
5. Disable everything in `Hard Drive BBS Priorities` and set the first entry to your bootable USB device (normally prefixed by "UEFI");
6. Clear `Boot override` entries;
7. Save and exit;
8. Install Windows 7 as usual.

The only way I found to check that the Windows 7 installer has booted in UEFI mode was to:

- Select a drive;
- Click on `New` in the Windows disk partitioner;
- Ensure that the 3 following partitions were created: `System`, `MSR` and `Primary`.

### Second step: Installing Windows 10

Repeat steps 1 to 7 mentioned above for Windows 7 by replacing the bootable USB device by the Windows 10 one. Install Windows 10 as usual.

I do not know if this is the case for everyone, but the logo of my motherboard manufacturer is displayed in place of the windows 10 logo when launching the Windows 10 installer in UEFI mode.

### Third step: Installing FreeBSD

I created a separate UEFI partition for FreeBSD because I am not experienced enough with this OS. As such, I can totally trashed FreeBSD and reinstall it without any modification.

1. Repeat steps 1 to 7 mentioned above for Windows 7 by replacing the bootable USB device by the FreeBSD 10 one;
2. Run the installer. You will be noticed that you have booted in UEFI mode;
3. Choose `GPT partition` when asked;
4. Create an EFI partition (I used approximately 200MB);
5. Create system partitions as you want;
6. Add a `swap` partition.

### Fourth step: Installing Debian

Repeat steps 1 to 7 mentioned above for Windows 7 by replacing the bootable USB device by the Debian one. Install Debian as usual. You will be noticed that you have booted in UEFI mode.

I do not know if it was needed but I created an EFI partition for Debian.

### Fifth step: Adding FreeBSD to Grub2

After having installed Debian, Grub2 should list the following entries:

- Debian;
- Debian memtest;
- Windows Bootloader;
- Something like `System setup` which allows you to access the bios.

Boot under Debian and open the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file with your favorite text editor and paste the following lines:

```
menuentry "FreeBSD <enter_your_version>"{
  insmod Z
  set root=(hdX,gptY)
  chainloader /boot/loader.efi
}
```

Where `Z` is the file system you have chosen during the installation of FreeBSD (e.g. ufs2, zfs), `X` is the number of the drive where FreeBSD is installed, and `Y` is the number of the partition where `/boot` is located.

Save, exit and run `update-grub` and reboot.

If you do not remember what should be the value of `X`, `Y` and `Z`, reboot your computer and type `c` under grub2. Run `ls` and `ls (hdX,gptY)` where `X` and `Y` are numbers which are listed by the first invocation of `ls`.

Comment: When Windows 10 boots up it shows Motherboard manufacturer logo, not the Windows blue logo. When you choose Windows bootloader from GRUB, do you see the Win7 and Win10 both options?

Comment: @Biswa Yes, but when I launch Windows 7, the computer reboot. I need to select Windows Bootloader in Grub again to boot Windows 7. Windows 10 boot directly when selected.

Comment: To remove that issue, see this [article](http://winaero.com/blog/avoid-two-reboots-with-windows-10-and-windows-7-dual-boot/).